# Error al convertir a lista en WCF

Tags: json, wcf

Este es mi codigo:

Mi implementación de servicio `.svc`

```
  public List<string> getClientes()
    {
        using (var context = new Model.CivarTransporteModelContainer())
        {
            return context.Cliente.Select(x => x.CLNombre).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Mi interfaz de servicio `.cs`

```
 [OperationContract]
    List<string> getClientes();
```

Aplicacion web

```
if (Request.QueryString["getClientes"] != null)
        {

            CivarTransporteService.View.CatalogsService wsclient = new CivarTransporteService.View.CatalogsService();
            List<CivarTransporteService.View.CatalogsService> clientList =wsclient.getClientes().ToList();

        }
```

Estoy teniendo un error en la parte de `= wsclient.getClientes().toList();`

```
Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List<string> to
 System.Collections.Generic.List<CivarTransporteService.View.CatalogsService>
```

Answer (score 2):

Estas retornando una lista de tipo `List<string>` la cual cuando recibes los datos en la Aplicacion web, los estas almacenando en una lista de tipo `List<CivarTransporteService.View.CatalogsService>` generando el error por tipo, debes recibir los datos en una lista de tipo `List<string>` .

Saludos

Comment: .. muchas gracias, algo tan sencillo se me complico :(

Comment: con gusto, es un placer haberte ayudado

Comment: @jm167 No te preocupes le puede pasar a los mejores

Answer (score 2):

Es que estas queriendo asignar una `List<string>` devuelta por `getClientes()` a una lista de `CatalogsService`

Deberias revisar la asignacion de los tipos de datos

Lo correcto seria

```
List<string> clientList = wsclient.getClientes();
```

Nota: no hace falta el `.ToList()` del final porque `getClientes()` ya devuelve este tipo de lista